# Socket Client Sends one long String rather than 3 Strings

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am writing a little client in C which sends three Strings to a Server far away. For example I send "FOO", "BAR", "FOOBAR" ill receive "FOOBARFOOBAR" "null", "null" on the other side.

Here is my Client Code:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int sock;           
struct sockaddr_in server;
char message[1000];
 
//socket Erstellen
sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (sock == -1)
{
    printf("Socket konnte nicht Erstellt werden\n");
}
puts("Socket erstellt\n");
 
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("194.94.82.231");    //Server Adressee
server.sin_family = AF_INET;                //Typ
server.sin_port = htons( 7896 );                //Port

//Zum Server Verbinden
if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("Verbindung Fehlgeschlagen!\n");
    return 1;
}
 
puts("Verbunden\n");
 
  /*Eingaben die zum Server gesendet werden sollen*/
int n=0;

    printf("message : ");
    scanf("%s" , message);
 
    n = write(sock , message , strlen(message));
    if (n < 0)
        printf("ERROR writing to socket");

    printf("message 2: ");
    scanf("%s" , message);
 
    n = write(sock , message , strlen(message));
    if (n < 0)
        printf("ERROR writing to socket");

    printf("message 3: ");
    scanf("%s" , message);
 
    n = write(sock , message , strlen(message));
    if (n < 0)
        printf("ERROR writing to socket");

puts("\nFertig\n"); 
close(sock);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "*error*" is that you are assuming that the data on a TCP sockets are sent as messages depending on how you do the write() in your code. 
This is true for UDP datagrams, but not for TCP.

A TCP socket behaves as a **stream** of data, hence you cannot assume how data on one end of the socket, will arrive on the other side.

What the protocol guarantee instead is that ALL data will arrive in the right order. Depending on the network condition (and the size of the buffer used to read data from the socket) you might receive all data in one shot, or several chunks.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) I used the TCP Protocol because i need to be sure that my Data is reaching the Server. So can i maby "Trick" the Socket if i send one String and first wait for a response bevore sending the next String ?

Comment: that's an option. Another one could be to add some king of semantic to the data sent on the socket, like, identify messages because you use some special byte or block of data to identify where a message begins and ends. Depending on your context some third-party library ike zmq could help you